# replace a string from user input in a CSV file (rewrite the file)

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, csv, shutil

I'm trying to make a function that lets the **user input** a file name, an old string to replace, and a new string.
I have a header in the file and it's made with another function in my project.
My issue is that when I do an inspection and test the code it displays the results needed, but when I go check the file in my directory nothing has changed so the func is not working basically.

another thing is that the **while loop** is not working properly, and I can't figure out why !you'll understand by running the code.

I have started coding recently so this is stressing me out.

The function:

```
import csv
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import shutil

def update_student_name():
    result = False
    f = input('Enter the file name with the extension .csv : ')
    temp_file = NamedTemporaryFile(mode= 'w' , delete=False)
    fields = ['Student Name', 'Student Grade']
    with open (f , 'r') as csv_file,temp_file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, fieldnames=fields)
        writer = csv.DictWriter(temp_file, fieldnames=fields,lineterminator='\r')
        while not result:
            old_name = input('Enter the name you would like to update/correct: ').title()
            new_name = input('Enter the new name: ').title()
            for data in reader:
                if data['Student Name'] == old_name:
                    print(data)
                    data['Student Name']=data['Student Name'].replace(data['Student Name'],new_name)
                    print(data)
                    # print(f'({old_name}) has been updated to ({new_name})')
                    result = True
                elif data['Student Name'] != old_name:
                    print("This name is not in the file. Please enter a valid name")
            writer.writerow(data)      
    shutil.move(temp_file.name , f)
```

The file I'm working on looks like this:

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the issue with the while loop? What do you want the while loop to do?

Comment: @arundeepchohan my idea is to keep entering student names if  we hit the else section (the name is not in the file) i thought i would include my code in a while loop then break it if the name is found

Comment: `writer.writerow(data)` happens only once after the loop is done, so you have to indent it more is it's inside the loop and it writes every row back into file

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko thanks it worked now but the "else" also gets executed !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So one of my friends found out that I needed to reorganize my code and I missed out on some concepts. apparently when dealing with files like my case `else` and `elif` can not be used that way inside a while loop.

1. `replace` can not be used in this matter and the result will not be saved anywhere so it won't be written on the file. using `update` is the better option since the files are read with `csv.Dictreader`.
2. file will start searching from the top of the file, so `elif` will be executed as well if it was written that way and `writrow` was placed at the end of the code.

So in case anyone needed it, the fixed code that is completely functional is:

```
def update_student_name():
result = False
f = input('Enter the file name with the extension .csv : ')
temp_file = NamedTemporaryFile(mode= 'w' , delete=False)
fields = ['Student Name', 'Student Grade']
with open (f , 'r') as csv_file,temp_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(temp_file, fieldnames=fields, lineterminator='\r')
    writer.writeheader()
    while True:
        old_name = input('Enter the name you would like to update/correct: ').title()
        new_name = input('Enter the new name: ').title()
        for data in reader:
            if data['Student Name'] == old_name:
                data.update({'Student Name':new_name})
                print(f'({old_name}) has been updated to ({data["Student Name"]})')
                result = True
            writer.writerow(data)
        if not result:
            print("This name is not in the file. Please enter a valid name")
        else:
            break
shutil.move(temp_file.name , f)
```